# Get k integers such that the ratio of sums of lists is maximum

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

> Given 2 arrays a and b of integers of length N, where a[i] denotes the area of the i'th building and b[i] denotes the price of the i'th building, select k buildings such that the sum of the prices of those buildings/sum of the areas of those buildings (ratio of total price to the total area) is maximum.

Could anybody suggest an approach to solve this problem? I got this in a test and was unable to solve it.

Comment: you must use dynamic programming? by the looks of things, looks like you just need a third `c` array with the ratio, and using something like a max-heap get the highest K ratio (and so using some kind of greedy algorithm)

Comment: @SaiKrishnaGarlapati  Pretty sure that's true as long as there's no negative numbers.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaGarlapati please share your attempt so far. Where are you stuck? What are your thoughts about the problem beyond "unable to solve"?

Comment: There is another way to word the problem (or rather, a subproblem): minimize the sum of the areas while maximizing the sum of the prices. The smaller the denominator, the larger the ratio. Besides that, more constraints are needed to optimize, for example, area shouldnt be negative, but can prices be?

Comment: @OneCricketeer "minimize the sum of the areas while maximizing the sum of the prices". You cannot do the two things at the same time.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Guess I am remembering my linear optimization classes incorrectly, then

Answer (score 1):

To solve this question recursion, When you are at ith index of your array, you could either select that building and consider its price and area for the final answer or you could just ignore this building and move to next index.

So whenever we choose any building increase `area_till_now` by area of current building and increase `price_till_now` by price of current building and decrease `remaining_k` by 1.

```
(0-based indexing)
double ans=0;
        
void recur(int current_index,double price_till_now,double area_till_now,int remaining_k){
     
    // we have selected k buildings.
    // so simply find the ratio and update maximum answer possible          
    if(remaining_k==0){
        double ratio=price_till_now/area_till_now;
        ans=max(ans,ratio);
        return;
    }
    // if we reach end of our array,
    // return as we cant select any more building
    if(current_index==n)return;

    // recur without selecting this building
    recur(current_index+1,price_till_now,area_till_now,left);

    // recur after selecting this building
    recur(current_index+1,price_till_now+price[current_index],area_till_now+area[current_index],left-1));
}
```

Since every building has either 2 choice for getting selected or not so it will have a O(2^n) time complexity.

**Update**: - My earlier dp solution had wrong calculations. Soon i'll update the optimized  and correct dp solution.

Comment: It looks like you may have misunderstood the question. It looks like your last max function is adding the current ratio to the result of recur, but that algebra is incorrect since the question seeks to maximise the total sum of the chosen prices divided by the total sum of the chosen areas. (Unless I misunderstood something.)

Comment: thank you for pointing out the mistake, the dp solution is wrong indeed.